# Nuget package files reappear after post build event

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, post-build-event

I have a nuget package which is like

```
  <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
 <metadata>
<id>Nuget1</id>
<version>1.4.21</version>
<title></title>
<authors></authors>
<owners></owners>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<projectUrl></projectUrl>
<description></summary>
<language>en-US</language>
</metadata>
<files>
<file src="nuget.targets" target="build\nuget.targets" />
<file src="..\.dll" target="lib\net472\.dll" />
</files>
<Project>
```

Target file looks like

```
 <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <ItemGroup>    
 <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\.dll">
  <Link>.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <PackagePath>lib</PackagePath>
  </None>
 
  </ItemGroup>
  </Project>
```

This is used in project C# library Sample.csproj .I then add post build event to this since these files need to be moved to subfolder in bin .

```
move  "$(TargetDir).dll" "$(TargetDir)subfolder"
```

Problem is Even after I move the file shown in output. Its still there after build is completed. Not sure whats happening . its moved during build and files reappear once build is completed